# Can Bluesnap IPN/Webhook support multiple IPN endpoints?

Tags: payment-gateway, webhooks, bluesnap

I want to feed transaction IPN data to 2 different back end systems for which I can configure 2 endpoint URLs. Can I configure 2 callback URL endpoints in BlueSnap Console so that the same transactional information reaches both systems?

Answer (score 0):

Yes Bluesnap IPN/Webhook support multiple IPN endpoints.
You can configure it in your Control Panel page under IPN/Webhook configuration page.